# Does DuplicateHandle() do any interprocess communication (IPC) and if not why target params?

Tags: c++, c, windows, ipc, handle

I am finding [DuplicateHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) very confusing. The third and fourth params, hTargetProcessHandle and lpTargetHandle seem to imply that this API function does some form of interprocess communication, but what I have been reading online seems to imply (without saying directly) that in fact this function cannot communicate with anything outside of the address space of its own process and that if you really do want to say copy the local process handle to another process you have to do that yourself manually.

So can someone please please take pity on me and tell me definitively whether or not this function does any IPC itself? Also if it doesn't do any IPC then what is the point of those two parameters? How can there be a 'target' if no data is sent and the output of this function is not visible to other processes?

At first I thought I could call GetCurrentProcess() and then use DuplicateHandle() to copy the local process handle to another process, but then I started to realize that it probably isn't that easy.

Comment: For kernel objects, it's straight forward for the `NtDuplicateObject` system call in the Object Manager to attach to the source and target processes to access and modify their kernel handle tables. Neither process is necessarily the calling process. The caller just needs `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` access on its handle for each process. Some additional IPC is required to communicate the new handle value to the target process.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter `hTargetProcessHandle` is documented as

```
A handle to the process that is to receive the duplicated handle.
```

That means that the handle (which is just a numeric value underneath) will become usable within the target process. However, how you get this handle into the target process and in what context it is to be used there is out of the scope of that function. Also note that "is to receive" points in the future and it refers to the result of the call, so it must be after the call has finished.

As an analogy, you want to allow a friend in your house. For that, you are creating a second key to your door. Just that doesn't mean that your friend can now unlock your door, because you first have to give it to them, but it's a first step.

Comment: Ok, but a guy cutting me a duplicate key would not need to know my friend's address. I would find it very suspicious and strange if he asked me for it. I would want to know why he wanted that information. Is this just like yet another security step? To continue the analogy is it like the guy making the key with a fingerprint reader so that it won't open the door unless my friend is using it? If so it seems like a ridiculous level of paranoia to me.

Comment: Yes, the key comes with a fingerprint reader so that only your the right person can use it. This is not so much a security measure but has practical reasons. Every process has a list of resources that are owned (or co-owned) by it but handled by the OS. A handle is often just an index into that process' list. The same index specifies a different resource for a different process, hence the need to know the process for which to duplicate the handle. This is just regular process separation in a multitasking environment.